# After Effects CS4, 3D double sided Image

Tags: images, animation, 3d-graphics

How would one go about making a 3D image in After Effect that has two different sides (Think of a poker card)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your working on something--like a playing card--that is flat then you need to create two separate layers--your front image on one and your back image on the other--that are the same size and at the same x & y position but 1 pixel apart from each other in z space. These both need to be parented to a null layer that you can then animate. Animating the null will animate the two others layers allowing them to stay locked to one another and appear as a two sided object.